# "You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected" when using rxjs6 and recompose's componentFromStreamWithConfig

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, rxjs6, recompose

When using rxjs 6.3.3 and recompose `componentFromStreamWithConfig`, I hit the error: `You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

I've tried providing a custom `rxjsConfig` object to `componentFromStreamWithConfig` as suggested in other questions relating to recompose and rxjs 6.

```
import "symbol-observable";
import {
  componentFromStreamWithConfig,
  createEventHandlerWithConfig
} from "recompose";
import { from } from "rxjs";

const rxjsConfig = {
  fromESObservable: from,
  toESObservable: stream => stream
};

export const createEventHandler = createEventHandlerWithConfig(rxjsConfig);
export const componentFromStream = componentFromStreamWithConfig(rxjsConfig);
```

The exported `componentFromStream` is used in a typical way in various components.

I would expect this to work given the rxjs 6 configuration - however the `fromESObservable` seems to be a problem (stacktrace points to `Object.from [as fromESObservable]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem seems to be:

1. `recompose` polyfills `Symbol.observable` by means of `symbol-observable`.
2. only when this polyfill is present, `rxjs` will recognize the object received from `componentFromStream` as an `Observable`, otherwise it throws the TypeError.

My workaround was to import `recompose` before anything of `rxjs` and the error disappeared.
Obviously the order of imports has relevance here, this has truly the potential to drive people mad!

In your case it would be sufficient to change the code *that uses your custom `componentFromStream`*:

- to either import your custom `componentFromStream` before any imports of `rxjs`,
- or to polyfill `Symbol.observable` explicitly by importing `symbol-observable`, but again on top of all `rxjs`-imports.

Comment: I was still hitting errors while moving imports around, but importing `symbol-observable` in my main index.js file fixed it. Thank you so much for the help & suggestions!